# How to form a Ternary for 3 with 1 constant

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

**Editing to Full Scenario** : I have two components, and Four buttons ! The default value of three buttons are `null`.  Lets say **a**,**b**,**c**,**d** are the various four buttons.

- In the first component, button **a** & **b** will be `null` by default so that, button **d** will be disabled.
- when user presses on **a** & **b** , a value will be assigned to **a** & **b**, so after **a** & **b** are assigned , then **d** should be enabled.
- in the second component, button **a** & **c** will have a default value of `null` and when they both got a value `onPressing`, again button **d** will be enabled.

Note that, components are rendered conditionally, so that only one component will be visible for users eyes !

Here is my code :

```
 <Button
     disabled={(this.state.quantityItemSelected === null || 
     this.state.deliveryOptionSelected === null) && 
     (this.state.timeSlotItemSelected === null) ? true : false} 
 />
```

The default constant is `this.state.quantityItemSelected === null` which is same for both.

It works fine with the condition in `()`, but about the first, when the `this.state.quantityItemSelected` becomes not a `null` at first and  and then `this.state.timeSlotItemSelected` becomes not a `null` it works fine,

but when i reverse that, when `this.state.timeSlotItemSelected` becomes not null at first the conditions goes to false.

My expected work is, it should be true when any thing is `null` with the constant.

Please help with this, do let me know what else needed to understand

Comment: Will the values, if falsey, always be `null`?

Comment: It's so confusing. But you don't need to use ternary operator. Simply use `&&` and `||` to satisfy the condition.

Comment: No, actually those values will change into something when users presses on respective ! So, there a constant which is same for both , so when that constant and other condition is null then it must be true when both become not null then it should be false !

Comment: Could you make a http://stackblitz.com example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i have a,b,c when a = null and b = null then it
>   should be true and when a = null and c = null it should be true, rest
>   conditions false.

Try the below , it will work ! You can use this.

```
(this.state.quantityItemSelected === null || this.state.deliveryOptionSelected === 
 null) && (this.state.timeSlotItemSelected === null || this.state.quantityItemSelected 
=== null) ? true : false
```

Do let me know, if its working !

Answer (score 0):

> For example - if i have a,b,c when a = null and b = null then it should be true and when a = null and c = null it should be true, rest conditions false.

You need to parenthesize latter two conditions and use `||` for them.

```
 <Button
   disabled={(
     (this.state.quantityItemSelected === null) &&
     (this.state.deliveryOptionSelected === null || this.state.timeSlotItemSelected === null)
   ) ? true : false} 
 />
```

Comment: Any idea about the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

> For example - if i have a,b,c when a = null and b = null then it should be true and when a = null and c = null it should be true, rest conditions false.

What you (in pseudo-logic notation) is `(!a && !b && c) || (!a && b && !c)` which expanded means

```js
function calculateConditions(a, b, c) {
  return (a === null && b === null && c !== null) || (a === null && b !== null && c === null);
}

//T - true, F - False. Shortenned to keep the formatting
const table = [
  ["FFF", calculateConditions( null     ,  null     ,  null)],
  ["FFT", calculateConditions( null     ,  null     , "not null")],
  ["FTF", calculateConditions( null     , "not null",  null)],
  ["FTT", calculateConditions( null     , "not null", "not null")],
  ["TFF", calculateConditions("not null",  null     ,  null)],
  ["TFT", calculateConditions("not null",  null     , "not null")],
  ["TTF", calculateConditions("not null", "not null",  null)],
  ["TTT", calculateConditions("not null", "not null", "not null")],
]

for (const [key, value] of table) {
  console.log(key, value)
}
```

Comment: Any idea about the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'this.state.quantityItemSelected' is 'a',  'this.state.deliveryOptionSelected' is 'b' and 'this.state.timeSlotItemSelected' is 'c', the condition should be:

```
this.state.quantityItemSelected === null && 
(this.state.deliveryOptionSelected === null ||
this.state.timeSlotItemSelected === null) ? true : false
```

or with a, b and c

```
a === null && (b === null || c === null)  ? true : false
```

If falsey values like zero, empty strings, etc. are not valid values for a, b and c, you could improve the code by doing:

```
disable = !a && (!b || !c)
```

**Answering edited question**

> In the first component, button a & b will be null by default so that, button d will be disabled.
>   when user presses on a & b , a value will be assigned to a & b, so after a & b are assigned , then d should be enabled.

This is a different scenario than the previous one.

```
disableButtonD = a === null && b === null;
```

or better

```
disableButtonD = !(a && b);
```

And for:

> in the second component, button a & c will have a default value of null and when they both got a value onPressing, again button d will be enabled.

```
disableButtonD = a === null && C === null;
```

or better

```
disableButtonD = !(a && C);
```

Following your constraints, you cannot use one sentence for both cases.
Of course, depending on what framework are you using you could have a function.

*Angular example:*

Component:

```
disableD(firstValue, secondValue) {
  return !(firstValue && secondValue)
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- first Button -->
<button [disabled]="disableD(a, b)"></button>

<!-- second button-->
<button [disabled]="disableD(a, c)"></button>
```

Comment: Actually, its not working either ! as, now it becomes true if either quantityItemSelected or timeSlotItemSelected  become not a null !

Comment: Any idea about the problem ?